# Como manter escolha de visualização do usuario no fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Tenho um sistema que usa o [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) , dependendo para o que o usuário esta usando no momento ele prefere um tipo de visualização, mês por exemplo, dependendo do que ele esta fazendo prefere outro tipo de visualização, semana por exemplo, e isso ele faz clicando nos botões que o fullcalendar cria. O que gera muito incomodo é que o usuário tem que passar por vários calendários e sempre ter que ficar clicando nos botões, existe alguma maneira de pegar essa escolha que ele fez e deixar como padrão para as próximas vezes em que ele acessar o sistema.
Logo que ele acessa eu já deixo marcado como default a opção de semana, então tenho algo assim hoje:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2015-12-23',
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, você pode fazer isso de diversas maneiras.

Para gravar as preferencias do usuario, aconselho você a fazer via ajax, gravar no banco de dados e carregar toda vez que o usuario entrar no sistema, porem você tambem pode fazer com [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) e guardar no próprio navegador do usuário as preferencias dele.

**Como ficaria com localstorage:**

Você pode criar um objeto com preferencias do usuario, exemplo:

```
//Setando preferencias
var prefRef = { 'id':321, 'tipo':'Mensal', 'cor':665533, 'itensPage':15};
localStorage.setItem('preferences', JSON.stringify(prefRef));

//Recuperando preferencias salva
var prefRef = json.parse(localStorage.getItem('preferences'));
alert('O usuario prefere a cor:' prefRef.cor );
```